# How do I specify x and/or leading padding for lead alignment text views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Given the following code snippet, I can align the leading edges of the text views but how can I specify that I want them to be aligned with their leading edges yet a certain number of pixels from the left edge of the actual VStack container?

```
VStack {
Text("Simple Swift Guide")
    .font(.title)
Text("SwiftUI Tutorials")
    .font(.subheadline)
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
 }
 .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
 .background(Color.yellow)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach for your snippet (if I understood your goal correctly) - alignment is external so internal `VStack` content can be any.

[image: demo]

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Simple Swift Guide")
            .font(.title)
        Text("SwiftUI Tutorials")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .padding(.leading, 25)
    .background(Color.yellow)
```